# vtd-xml xpath, how to use variable expression?

Tags: java, xml, xpath, android-xml, vtd-xml

I'm trying to get definitions for a specific word which match to user's input string from an xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<diction>
<article>
<key>a</key>
<definition>
    ένας, μια, μία, ένα
</definition>
</article>
<article>
<key>a</key>
<definition>
α (στερητικό)
</definition>
</article>
<article>
<key>all</key>
<definition>
όλος, όλη, όλο
</definition>
</article>
<article>
<key>a.m</key>
<definition>
π.μ., πρωί
</definition>
</article>
<article>
<key>base</key>
<definition>
base
</definition>
</article>
</diction>
```

code:

```
ap.declareVariableExpr("myexpr", xmlInput.getText().toString().replaceAll("\\s+$", ""));

ap.selectXPath("/diction/article/key[local-name()=string($myexpr)]");
//ap.evalXPathToString();
//ap.selectXPath("/diction/article/key");
ap.bind(vn);

int i;
while ((i=ap.evalXPath()) !=-1){
    i=vn.getText();
    vn.push();
    if(vn.toElement(VTDNav.NEXT_SIBLING, "definition")) {
        int j = vn.getText();
        if (j != -1)

        parsedData=parsedData+"word: " +        vn.toNormalizedString(i) + "\n"
        + "definition: " + vn.toNormalizedString(j) +"\n";
        Log.i("first", parsedData);
    }
    vn.pop();
}
ap.resetXPath();
```

The above code gives me all words/definitions and not only those who match with the input string. Is the xpath expression correct? What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide us with example of user's input and how it matches to the word in xml?

Comment: for e.g the user enter the word "base" in xmlInput edittext. I declare this as "myexpr" variable to use it in selectXPath, so to get only the definition for "base". I've done this with sax xml parser, but it's slow.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function in AutoPilot called declareVariableExpression()that allows you to declare variable expressions.

Comment: I'm using this function(see above), but I don't get the desired result. I've searched a lot about vtd-xml and xpath the last days but I didn't find anything for my case. There are some related tutorials but using numbers, not strings. So I imported the xml file to sqlite database and I'll try this way, which maybe it's faster from xml parsing(my file is 6MB). I haven't use xml parsing at all until now and most for this I wanted to use it. But I found difficult to manipulate vtd-xml and sax is very slow for my case(for this I searched and found vtd-xml).

Comment: what is in your xmlInput string?

Comment: I looked at your code, did you enable namespace when parsing the xml file?

Comment: I gave up vtd-xml because the database way gives results very fast for the case that this will be helpful for someone else in the future, no I didn't. So maybe this was the problem.